Joint Bavli and Yerushalmi Gemara edition
Is there a Talmud book that has both of the Yerushalmi and Bavli side by side commenting on any given Mishnah? I think this would greatly elucidate the meaning of a Mishnah, which, afterall, is the point of the Talmud.

https://www.academia.edu/50763431/%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A6%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%99_%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99_%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%94_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9C?sm=b

I am unaware of such a work ,which would seen like a very sizable amount of material. However there is a sefer(אמרי במערבא) that references the Bavli and Yerushalmi for each mashecta . Very useful when trying to see what the Bavli and Yerushalmi concur on or disagree on .
Sample page :

